# Jquery / Javascript: Is there a way to check if ajax is still in progress when user revisits a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that will generate details of a record. When the user comes to this page, he/she will have to press a 'generate' button to create the details of the record. Since it will take some time to generate the record, the moment the user clicks the button, it will trigger an ajax request.

```
$("#generate_record_button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    // Show some loading messages, and spinner
    $.ajax({
      url: "<generate-record-url/>",
      method: 'get',
      data: {id: <recordID>},
      cache: false
    }).success(function (data) {
       // Do something on success
       // Show some success messages
       // Remove spinner
    }).fail(function (data) {
       // Do something on failure
       // Show some error messages
       // Remove spinner
       $(this).removeClass('disabled');
    });
});
```

In the code, currently when the user presses the button, the button will be disabled to prevent from potential multiple ajax requests being triggered if user keeps pressing the button. By right, user should only press the button once and just let the ajax handles the request accordingly.

My question is, is there a way to check if the ajax request is still running in the event when the user leaves the page? (Eg: refresh the page, navigate to other page, etc etc). What I would hope to achieve is that if the user re-visits back this page while the ajax is still processing the record (for that particular record ID), the button will remain disabled so that user can't press it and will see some loading messages. Is this possible?

Comment: Then you will need to store the state of the user request on the server somehow, because when a user leaves the page and return, the client page will have no idea if the server has finished processing the request (i.e. generating the record).

Comment: _“is there a way to check if the ajax request is still running in the event when the user leaves the page?”_ - if it is, then this navigation to a different page will make the browser _cancel_ it. (Whether processing on the server side still proceeds after the client closed the connection, depends on the specifics of the implementation.)

Comment: AJAX requests should be cancelled automatically if user navigates away (incl. reloads) the page.

Comment: Yes, this behavior is possible but not in the way you've described it. The client sends a request to start the process. The server responds almost immediately. Then the client polls (or uses a websocket) to continouosly be informed about the state of the process and to wait until it finishes. This way you can leave the website or reload it.

Comment: Ok, how do i inform abort the ajax request or inform the user that the request will be terminated if the user decides to leave the page? I tried the beforeunload and on('unload') callbacks; they don't seem to trigger when user tries to navigate away from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user should not leave the page while ajax is running since it will be cancelled.

How about

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  if ($("#generate_record_button").hasClass("disabled"))
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this code, but somehow it isn't showing the message 'Are you sure you want to leave?' when i try to leave the page, like hitting the refresh button. I excluded the if condition in the code. Not sure if I am missing something

Comment: It only reacts while the button has the class disabled. Tey to not remove the class on the button